# Shell - jq: Turning json list of `keys.childkeys` into list of lists

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I am using jq to parse a `json file`. This is the current output from `jq`:

```
[
 "key1.childk2",
 "key2.childk3"
]
```

I would like to turn this into a readable json format itself as list of lists like below:

```
    [ 
      ["key1","childk2"],
      ["key2","childk3"]
    ]
```

I would ideally prefer to do this with `jq`, however any other shell tool that can work on shell variables is fair game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jq `split` filter:

```sh
jq '[.[] | split(".")]'
```

```json
[
  [
    "key1",
    "childk2"
  ],
  [
    "key2",
    "childk3"
  ]
]
```

You should use it somewhere in the original jq command

Comment: Thanks for this!. Yes, can be piped directly at the end of the   last `jq` command that is producing my original output.

Answer (score 2):

With jq you can *structurally* turn the input into your desired JSON document using simple filters like `map(./".")`, but regarding the requested *readability*, the output wouldn't have exactly your desired *formatting*.

Without any further flags, jq would pretty-print the output as:

```json
[
  [
    "key1",
    "childk2"
  ],
  [
    "key2",
    "childk3"
  ]
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Xwylv798eq)

Using the `--compact-output` or `-c` flag would compress the whole JSON document into one line, not just the elements of the outer array:

```json
[["key1","childk2"],["key2","childk3"]]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qV2MmBMJZE)

So, if you *really* wanted to, you could also glue together the parts yourself as you like them to be formatted from within jq, but honestly, I would discourage you from doing so as by circumventing jq's internal JSON composer you might end up outputting invalid JSON.

```sh
jq -r '"[", "  " + (map(./"." | tojson) | .[:-1][] += ",")[], "]"'
```

```json
[
  ["key1","childk2"],
  ["key2","childk3"]
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XQpHK9VgvT)

Comment: Nice, I didn't thought of the division for splitting strings +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `ruby` to do that:

```
ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.parse($<.read).map{|e| e.split(".")}.to_json' file

[["key1","childk2"],["key2","childk3"]]
```

Or if you want it **pretty**:

```
ruby -r json -e 'puts JSON.pretty_generate(
            JSON.parse($<.read).map{|e| e.split(".")})
' file
[
  [
    "key1",
    "childk2"
  ],
  [
    "key2",
    "childk3"
  ]
]
```

Or you can produce your *precise* format:

```
ruby -r json -e '
l=[]
JSON.parse($<.read).map{|e| l << e.split(".").to_s}
puts "[\n\t#{l.join(",\n\t")}\n]"
' file 
[
    ["key1", "childk2"],
    ["key2", "childk3"]
]
```

Comment: I noticed that you prefer `$<` over `ARGF` in your ruby one-liners; is there a reason for that? +1

Comment: I think it is a cool sigil. A uniquely ruby thing.